# Deny running batch files

Tags: batch, batch-file, group-policy, windows-server-2012

How can I deny users of my network to run any batch files in their user level? I want it to return them an access denied message OR delete the script entirely. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use users `Group policy` -> `Prevent access to command prompt`, there is an option to disallow batch scripts.

[image: Self explanatory]

Comment: It only stops users running cmd.exe They can still run batch files

Comment: No, there is a sub-option to deny executing batch files.